# Averages of the same population but different samples

Tags: statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics, descriptive-statistics

Let's assume I have a finite population N and that I draw two samples from it n1, and n2. A single sample can belong to both samples.

Calculating the averages for each sample and the confidence intervals is simple enough. I want to know can I combine the two samples somehow to obtain a tighter confidence intervals on the average.

Comment: Please reference the link. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/55999/is-it-possible-to-find-the-combined-standard-deviation